# How do I backup Chrome OS?

Tags: backup, restore, chrome-os, chrome-book

I tried to use Acronis Backup & Restore Universal which boot form USB media, but it doesn't work. It doesn't boot from USB removable media. It looks like Chromebooks don't have a BIOS like normal laptops do.

I have installed OpenJDK, Android Studio and some IDEs. I just want to backup this sort of apps which I don't need to reinstall them when I reinstall the Chrome OS.

Comment: I thought the point of Chrome OS is that you store everything in the Google cloud and not worry about these things at all?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use Acronis backup & restore universal which boot form USB media,but it doesn't work,it doesn't boot from USB removal media,it looks like Chromebook doesn't have BIOS like normal laptop do.

A Chromebook is not an IBM compatible PC or "Wintel" computer. It doesn't have a system firmware that provides the full functionality of a BIOS on Wintel machines. Re-thinking the whole boot process and re-designing it to be safe and fast greatly improved user experience.

So backup programs meant for Wintel machines will not work by default because they rely on components that are not there. It's like if you expect a Mac program to work on a PC. Or if you don't like that comparison, like executing a Haiku or Redox x86_64 program on a PowerPC platform running BSD. Acronis claims that their Universal Restore technology disassociates backup data from hardware. You may file a ticket with Acronis but I don't see a need to go down that route and I will explain why.

> I have installed OpenJDK , Android Studio and some IDEs,I just want to backup this sort of apps which I don't need to reinstall them when I reinstall the Chrome OS .

Why would you want to reinstall Chrome OS? Do you even know and understand how to do that? It sounds to me like you got a Chromebook and you are trying to apply your general "PC"/Wintel knowledge to Chromebooks. Unfortunately you don't know enough about general computing and you are in doubt of the actual content of your data thus you have to rely on programs that approach a problem in a certain way which is not actually necessary to solve your problem.

Acronis (among others) is known primarily for products that generate full images of computers. I'm sure they have a way of creating incremental backups which is how you reduce the amount of time and resources spent backing up data in a professional environment where you have the responsibility for several corporate customers with a lot of servers and clients. But that is a very traditional way of backing up data which usually fails on desktop clients that are not always on when the backup is scheduled. Also many Chromebooks ship with slower EMMC flash chips that don't like to be written from the first to the last block. Many of them slow down to a crawl during this operation, it's also not so smart when you are using other storage technologies like [SMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording). Planning your data backup strategy as a scheduled full take can get you into trouble.

Summary:

- You don't need to make an entire drive image of a Chromebook. Google already provides [one](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en) and a sophisticated update mechanism featuring [two separate system partitions](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format#TOC-Drive-partitions) ensuring that you always have a booting system thus eliminating many reasons to reinstall an entire system which other platforms were known for in past decades.
- You should adapt to a workflow where you have your live project data and configuration data (your custom settings) not just in one place but synced across devices whenever possible. That is how you minimize downtime and be productive in a world where computing devices have become abundant. By all means, you don't have to use a certain cloud provider. If solutions like Nextcloud/Owncloud, Syncthing, WebDAV, fileshares and scripts work for you, you can pick whatever you prefer.
- Know your data, how you configured settings and where. Apps like Android Studio or Visual Studio Code can be run on typical Linux distributions, Chromebooks, Windows, Mac and so forth. Once you know where the necessary parts are you can get rid of the unnecessary crufty parts (at least in your backup). You will be productive with a tiny amount of notes, instructions and a svelte collection of files. It's not as difficult as it seems at first sight.

Comment: thank you very much,your answer is really useful

Comment: alright,btw I have Mac book pro and laptop ,i have Chromebook as well,it has intel CPU,I thought acnrois backup was working on Chromebook,now I think I might know how to deal with chromebook

Comment: If you really want to make an image of the device and it has an x86 processor, then you can install https://mrchromebox.tech/ firmware, this will allow you to boot the old way. But entering developer mode will wipe your data and is not a recommended way to run a chromebook.

Comment: I have made my chromebook into Developer mode though,I'm going to try your solution,thanks